# A slight misunderstanding with a UML diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

So my question concerns a UML diagram for a program. My professor seems to like to switch up the way he diagrams and he hasn't been online for the night and I'm not sure when he will be next, so what I have figured out so far, is that the project I'm working on has two implementations and the left half of this diagram seems to describe one and the right half seems to describe the other, I have looked up the common UML diagram meanings but still am a little foggy as to their pertinence to this uml. Also as this class is strictly online we are allowed to ask questions online and seek outside resources, however, a simple UML diagram understanding in my opinion could not be misconstrued as overreaching into the territory of "cheating," in any class.
here is what i know:

1) left is one implementation right is another.

2) the left side uses a database class which is then used by the Awards ceremony

3) the right side has a class called baseballAwards which extends the AbstractBaseballAwards

what I want to know is:

1)what the link between AwardsCeremony and AbstractBaseballAwards is?

2) does my professor mean to say that awardsCeremoney is used by both implementations and that the link is actually between AwardsCeremony and baseballAwards?

3) any further explanation would be lovely :)

[image: UML Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, best resource to learn UML quickly: **UML Distilled**, 3rd edition, by Martin Fowler.

For what concerns your example:

1. It is an **Association**
2. In the end, yes: *AbstractBaseballAwards* is an abstract class (AKA interface) so it cannot be instantiated. However, you will have an association with an *AbstractBaseballAwards*, then instantiated as a BaseballAwards object.
3. Read the book: it's very short and useful.